# AWS kubernetes load balancer terminate SSL on port 443 and forward to service on port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, kubernetes

I'm trying to set up my EKS cluster in AWS with [Nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress).

Nginx ingress controller creates a service of type LoadBalancer which in turn creates a ELB instance that's mapped to the node ports of the service.

I'd like to have the SSL certificate managed by AWS, not the kubernetes cluster, so I imported it into the AWS Certificate Manager and added an annotation to the nginx service:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <certificate_arn>
```

So far it's standard stuff. The load balancer is now doing the SSL termination and the subsequent communication between it and the cluster is unencrypted, which is what I wanted. The only problem is that instead of this:

```
[Client] -> HTTPS (443) -> [ELB (SSL termination)] -> HTTP (80) -> [Service]
```

I get this

```
[Client] -> HTTPS (443) -> [ELB (SSL termination)] -> HTTP (443) -> [Service]
```

As you can see, the ELB doesn't change the port from 443 to 80 and the communication gets rejected by the Nginx pod because it receives unencrypted traffic on port 443.

I tried a similar thing with SSL/TCP ELB but the same problem occurs.

I searched but couldn't find any way, how to tell the ELB to send the unecrypted traffic to port 80. ANy ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: please, in addition to describe your issue, would be good if you add your kubernetes yamls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure your Ingress service to use `targetPort: http` even when using the `443` port.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/e68b68d20cfc0e083f6b33413bc27887a05985f5/deploy/provider/aws/service-l7.yaml) of using Nginx Ingress and Amazon ELB with Layer 7 (HTTP/HTTPS) listeners:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:XXXXXXXX:certificate/XXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: http  # <--- PAY ATTENTION HERE
```

Comment: My request works on http, but the same times out when I invoke using https.  I changed target port as mentioned by you to http still no luck. How can I debug where exactly has the issue in kubernetes?